# Что такое px dp и sp и как переводить одно в другое?

Tags: android, android-sdk

Только начал обучаться Android SDK и столкнулся с проблемой, что в разных разрешениях объекты отображаются по разному, если использовать пиксели. Как перевести пиксели в dp?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, там нет информации как переводить одно в другое.

Comment: @Dariuz, кроме пикселей там все есть. А о них стоит забыть в мобильной разработке, что для Android, что для iOS.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, у меня макет в пикселях. Как перевести пиксели в dp. Вы о другом говорите. Я и хочу делать в dp, но как мне макет в dp переделать?

Comment: Обращайтесь к тому, кто макет рисовал, пусть в dp перерисует. `The first pitfall you must avoid is using pixels to define distances or sizes.` Отсюда взято: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, а вы не знаете, как в фотошопе dp использовать?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, и скажите пожалуйста сколько dp в высоту и в ширину?

Comment: @Dariuz, я не дизайнер. Информацию можно найти к примеру здесь: https://screensiz.es/phone Обычно ориентируются в dp на 360х640 и чтобы корректно отображался на минимальном 320х480, если мы о смартфонах.